# Handle SQL exceptions in Entity Framework if a stored procedure in SQL Server already handles them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I am using an ASP.NET RESTful API with EF Core to communicate with a SQL Server database. I want to execute some stored procedures that handle exceptions. Do I also need to wrap my C# code to call the stored procedures in a `try catch` block?

In case I do not wrap the code in a try catch block, will C# throw an exception even if my stored procedure handled the exception?

Comment: If the sql server layer does handle exceptions, that means it should return something meaningful for your code to be able to log/rethrow/notify user. So e.g if the result is -1 throw new MyCustomDataException

Comment: Any time your application interacts with another process you should expect communication failures and handle exceptions as needed. Many things can cause an exception to be received by your application that are completely outside of the procedure's logic and its ability to catch exceptions. The answer to your last question is simple - try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your stored proc handle try catch block, then your stored proc will never throw an error because it will trap within proc. So there is no need to wrap try catch block from c#